# PDF Laravel snappy : Text is broken

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, snappy

so, this issues has occurred when I downloaded my multiple PDF files. There are some broken text :

[image]

in this case, I'm using merge command :

```
$mergeCommand = "gs -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dNumRenderingThreads=1 -dNOGC - 
dBandBufferSpace=500000000 -dBufferSpace=1000000000 -sOutputFile={$storagePath}/{$uuidSession}.pdf 
{$pathOutputs}";

$process = Process::fromShellCommandline($mergeCommand);
$process->setTimeout(0);
$process->run();
```

but when I tried to download a single file the text is not broken, has anyone ever experienced it like me? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with using font URL in CSS